# Files, URIs, and URLs conflicting in Java

Tags: java, file, url, path, uri

I am getting some strange behavior when trying to convert between Files and URLs, particularly when a file/path has spaces in its name.  Is there any safe way to convert between the two?

My program has a file saving functionality where the actual "Save" operation is delegated to an outside library that requires a URL as a parameter.  However, I also want the user to be able to pick which file to save to.  The issue is that when converting between File and URL (using URI), spaces show up as "%20" and mess up various operations.  Consider the following code:

```
//...user has selected file
File userFile = myFileChooser.getSelectedFile();
URL userURL = userFile.toURI().toURL();

System.out.println(userFile.getPath());
System.out.println(userURL);

File myFile = new File(userURL.getFile());

System.out.println(myFile.equals(userFile);
```

This will return false (due to the "%20" symbols), and is causing significant issues in my program because Files and URLs are handed off and often operations have to be performed with them (like getting parent/subdirectories).  Is there a way to make File/URL handling safe for paths with whitespace?

P.S. Everything works fine if my paths have no spaces in them (and the paths look equal), but that is a user restriction I cannot impose.

Comment: Why don't you do the conversion URL -> File also via URI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you use URL to construct the second file:

```
File myFile = new File(userURL.getFile());
```

If you stick to the URI, you are better off:

```
URI userURI = userFile.toURI();
URL userURL = userURI.toURL();
...
File myFile = new File(userURI);
```

or

```
File myFile = new File( userURL.toURI() );
```

Both ways worked for me, when testing file names with blanks.

Comment: That seems to work, URI also includes a toPath() method that I found useful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use instead..

```
System.out.println(myFile.toURI().toURL().equals(userURL);
```

That should return `true`.

Comment: Perhaps, but that code was just a demonstration.  This still doesn't resolve the issue of creating a file from URL that I can manipulate properly.