# Locating a file using Uri and file path

Tags: android, file-io, uri

what is the difference between Uri and filepath?

They actually seem to be same but i don't  know where the difference lies.

Comment: Why not read the corresponding wikipedia entries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between a Resource, URI, URL, Path and File in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27845223/whats-the-difference-between-a-resource-uri-url-path-and-file-in-java)