# Which path should I use?

Tags: java, io, filepath

I have a class that calls a file and a class that runs the other, however, I don't know where I should put it. This file is in src\coutner\bldad\Runtime.java. The PATH string says to store in "pic\tricks.png":

```
public static final String TRICKS_PATH = "pic\\tricks.png";
```

and

```
JLabel tricksbg = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File(TRICKS_PATH))));
```

This file is in src\Main.java. Now where this calls:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    Runtime.main(concat(new String[] {""}, args));
 }
```

Should I specify the image file in "src\coutner\bldad\pic\tricks.png" or "src\pic\tricks.png"?

Comment: You shouldn't be betting these images as files regardless as you are trying to do. They should be obtained as resources.

Comment: Please see [What's the difference between a Resource, URI, URL, Path and File in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27845223/whats-the-difference-between-a-resource-uri-url-path-and-file-in-java)